# Why is Cloud Function taking different timezone/times?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pytz, google-cloud-scheduler

Background :
Triggering a CF via Cloud Scheduler: Image below: Its scheduled to run at 7 am Australia/Sydney time and trigger two cloud functions:

[image]

Cloud Function : Regions is us-central1. Code used :

```
# Global variable:

tz=pytz.timezone('Australia/Sydney')
naive_dt = datetime.now(tz=tz)
since = datetime.strftime(naive_dt - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d') #yesterday's date 
until = datetime.strftime(naive_dt - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d') #yesterday's date 

def honda_reporting_automation(event,context):

    print("New Day")
    print("current Function Execution date time",naive_dt)
    print("since",since)
    print("until",until)
```

Weird cloud function behaviour: 
1. Though the cloud scheduler triggers the job at 7:00 am, and I have set the server timing to my local timing in my code, still the timing of execution differs.It takes US Timings(1 day lag) (Image below)

[image]

2. 2nd Cloud function shows different time of start(a difference of 4 mins from 1st one) , though triggered at the same time by the same scheduler.

[image]

3. When triggered manually via Cloud Scheduler using "Run now" option, they behave as expected and shows correct timings. (image 3)

[image]

anyone came across this weird behaviour ? and any idea how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 4):

What is the error here? you are asking the function to be excecuted at 7:00 AEDT and it's being executed at this time. The server where the Cloud Function runs is in US central so the log trowed by the system to stackdriver will reflect this timezone. Since Cloud Functions is a Serverless product you can't modify the timezone of the machine where the function is excecuted.

Also according to the [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) you are not converting the time correctly.

You should use something similar to:

```
naive_dt = datetime.now(timezone(tz))
```

instead of:

```
naive_dt = datetime.now(tz=tz)
```

Here is an example of my code working:

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

def hello_world(request):
    fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
    nowutc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
    now_australia = nowutc.astimezone(timezone('Australia/Sydney'))
    print(now_australia.strftime(fmt))

    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return str(now_australia.strftime(fmt))
```

Log:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment mate. Couple of things: Why is the execution time different (fig 1 and 2) though they are fired at same time in same project/location. Second:In my point 3 above , why the CF function execution time exactly matched with my logs/server time if we can't modify the timezone and if pytz code was incorrect ? Lastly, what is the best was to set the date-time for a Cloud Function ? (coz if I need current day - 1 data , that 'current day' might differ based on the server/location CF is running). Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Regarding your first question, I don't know what your function does or how many time takes to your function to be excecuted but you should keep in mind that there is a delay between when something happens in your function and when the log is printed. This delay may be the reason of why in 1 and 2 the AEDT time doesn't match. Second, the time displayed on the left side is your local time, not the time of the Cloud Function. The time displayed on the right side is the time printed by your code

Comment: For your last question I don't know what are you trying to implement so I can't tell you the best way to get the date of currentdate -1 but seems like your code was working as expected if your goal is that (line 3 & 4 of your code). I just added a full code sample so you can see how I'm getting the time and converting it to AEDT